# Kibana 4 custom dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Kibana 4 with aggregation feature has proved very useful to me, however I need to do application-side join inorder to work with the available data.

Is there a way in kibana 4 to execute a application-side join (set of queries + code) and return a dashboard?

I read online docs of how to do this as scripted dashboard (kibana 3) http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/templated-and-scripted-dashboards.html however my understanding is that this is no longer supported in kibana 4.

Comment: Related: [Build your own dashboard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/tutorial-build-dashboard.html).

Comment: [Creating Custom Kibana Visualizations: A How-To Guide](https://logz.io/blog/kibana-visualizations/)

Comment: Example: https://github.com/logzio/kibana-visualizations/tree/master/traffic_light_vis

Answer (score 2):

Kibana 4 is in development (Beta 3 is comming soon). You should look at the github project and browse issues to see watch is/will be implemented in the next versions of kibana 4.

If there is no issue, you should create new one to submit the feature.

Link : https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues?q=is%3Aissue+scripted+dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get. but you should extract the extra fields for that. Through logstash extract the more fields using filter..

- Im showing you down with custom dashboards. You need to create dashboard and add visualizations and save it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It possible using the new version for sure.. (4.0.1) you can very easily manipulate the client side with additional json inputs, or you can create your own queries that will be rendered as a dashboards widgets.[image]

Comment: is there an example or a tutorial on this somewhere?